# azure batch blender custom image

Tags: azure, rendering, blender

I am exploring the possibilities of distributed rendering on azure with batch explorer.

I loved the fact that out of the box you get a lot of tools for 3d rendering, even specifically for blender. However I am having some trouble setting it up for my needs.

On batch explorer the blender gallery template is not up to date. I tried to render something and I was getting black geometry. After some troubleshooting I understood it was because of the principled shader that has only been added in 2.79. If I don't use the principled shader all is good, so I believe the version of blender in the template is outdated.

For this reason I am trying to find a way to create a custom linux build with blender 2.79b, but I got stuck. I am a bit lost with all the guides, tutorials and so on.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction for what I actually need to do.

Thank you very much for any help in advance!

Bernardo

Comment: What is the exact problem you have?

Comment: hi Jeroen, thanks for the comment. I am not able to create a custom linux image with blender 2.79b installed. The default template on batch explorer have an outdated version of blender, so I need to do a linux image with the newer version myself. I am following guides and tuts but I couldn't do it so far, I was wondering if someone can help me with this.

I think this is what I am trying to do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images

Unfortunately my experience is in 3d, I don't have much knowledge as a developer.